# Get the PHP variable value in real time and display it in the alert box before submitting to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have this page that input details for library materials. I can manage to post the field and save it to the database using native codes. But, I find it more useful if the page would display first the details being inputted using a confirm box, that if clicked yes it will then save to database, but if "cancel" it will return to the page without erasing the field contents (so they can edit it again). I think it was an Ajax.

These are my codes:

This is the page where the form displays: "_invent.php"

```
<?php
//INVENTORY FOR LIBRARIAN
session_start();
require_once('securitytwo.php');
//SECURITY
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","lemuel","12345"); //connect to the server
      mysql_select_db("integratedlibrarysystem"); //connect to the database

       $query="Select * from libinventuser where username='{$_SESSION['user']}' and password='{$_SESSION['pass']}'";
       $result=mysql_query($query);
       $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num!=0)
        {
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="clarify.js"></script>
<link href="tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php include("clarify.php"); ?>
</head>
INVENTORY
<br><br><br>

<ol id="toc">
    <li><a href="#inventory"><span>Inventory</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#addmaterial"><span>Add Material</span></a></li>
</ol>

<div class="content" id="inventory">
Inventory
</div>

<!-- Add Library Material inside the database-->
<div id="addmaterial" class="content">
<h2>Add Material</h2>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="savetoinvent.php">
<?php include('addmaterialform.php'); //Add material form?> 
<div class="space"><input type="submit" id="save" value="Save"></div>
</form>
<div id="message"></div>
</div>

<script src="activatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
activatables('page', ['inventory', 'addmaterial']);
</script>
<a href="adminmainpage.php">Back</a>
<?php
}
else{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page for the fields where I input the details of materials: "addmaterialform.php"

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script language="javascript">
var last = 1;
var first = 1;
var middle = 1; 
var ctr = 1;
var ctra = 1;
var subj = 1; 
function addInput() {
ctr++;
last++;
first++;
middle++; // Para every time na iclick ni user ang addInput mag-increment siya. Parang eto na din yung unique identifier ng author
document.getElementById('author').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
"<input type='text' name='l"+last+"' placeholder='last name' value=''> " +
"<input type='text' name='f" +first+ "' placeholder='first name' value=''> " +
"<input type='text' name='m" +middle+ "' placeholder='middle name' value=''><br>") ;
document.getElementById('ctr').value = ctr;
document.getElementById('last').value = last;
document.getElementById('first').value = first;
document.getElementById('middle').value = middle;
}
function addSubjectMatter() {
ctra++;
subj++;
document.getElementById('subjmat').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
"<input type='text' name='s"+subj+"' value=''><br>") ;
document.getElementById('ctra').value = ctra;
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="ctr" id="ctr">
<input type="hidden" name="ctra" id="ctra">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="subcontainer">
    <div class="label">Title</div> <!--Title-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="60px"></div>
    <div class="label">Author(s)</div> <!--Author(s)-->
    <div class="inputs">
        <div id="author">
        <!--Last Name--><input type="text" name="l1" placeholder="last name" value=""><!-- Ginawa kong "last_1" yung "last" -->
        <!--First Name--><input type="text" name="f1" placeholder="first name" value=""><!-- Ginawa kong "first_1" yung "first" -->
        <!--Middle Name--><input type="text" name="m1" placeholder="middle name" value=""><!-- Ginawa kong "middle_1" yung "middle" -->
        <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add" /><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Edition</div> <!--Edition-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="edition" id="edition"></div>
    <div class="label">Place of Publication</div> <!--Place of Publication-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="place" size="60px"></div>
    <div class="label">Copyright date/Publication date</div> <!--Copyright date/Publication date-->
    <div class="inputs">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr><td  align="left"  >   
        <!-- Month -->
        <select name="cpdm" value=''>Select Month</option>
        <option value='01'>January</option>
        <option value='02'>February</option>
        <option value='03'>March</option>
        <option value='04'>April</option>
        <option value='05'>May</option>
        <option value='06'>June</option>
        <option value='07'>July</option>
        <option value='08'>August</option>
        <option value='09'>September</option>
        <option value='10'>October</option>
        <option value='11'>November</option>
        <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Day -->
        </td><td  align="left">   
        <select name="cpdd">
        <option value='01'>01</option>
        <option value='02'>02</option>
        <option value='03'>03</option>
        <option value='04'>04</option>
        <option value='05'>05</option>
        <option value='06'>06</option>
        <option value='07'>07</option>
        <option value='08'>08</option>
        <option value='09'>09</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='11'>11</option>
        <option value='12'>12</option>
        <option value='13'>13</option>
        <option value='14'>14</option>
        <option value='15'>15</option>
        <option value='16'>16</option>
        <option value='17'>17</option>
        <option value='18'>18</option>
        <option value='19'>19</option>
        <option value='20'>20</option>
        <option value='21'>21</option>
        <option value='22'>22</option>
        <option value='23'>23</option>
        <option value='24'>24</option>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='26'>26</option>
        <option value='27'>27</option>
        <option value='28'>28</option>
        <option value='29'>29</option>
        <option value='30'>30</option>
        <option value='31'>31</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Year -->
        </td><td  align="left"  >   
        <input type="text" name="cpdy" size="4" placeholder="year">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="label">No. of pages:</div> <!--No. of pages-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="nopa" size="5px"></div>
    <div class="label">No. of copies:</div> <!--No. of copies-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="nocop" size="5px"></div>
    <div class="label">Subject matter</div> <!--Subject matter-->
    <div class="inputs">
        <div id="subjmat">
        <input type="text" name="s1" value=""> <!--subject matter than can be use as the tag of the subject-->
        <input type="button" onclick="addSubjectMatter()" name="add" value="Add" /><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space"><b>Purchase details:</b></div> <!--Purchase details-->
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="label">Date of purchase</div> <!--Date of purchase-->
    <div class="inputs">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr><td  align="left"  >   
        <!-- Month -->
        <select name="dapurm" value=''>Select Month</option>
        <option value='01'>January</option>
        <option value='02'>February</option>
        <option value='03'>March</option>
        <option value='04'>April</option>
        <option value='05'>May</option>
        <option value='06'>June</option>
        <option value='07'>July</option>
        <option value='08'>August</option>
        <option value='09'>September</option>
        <option value='10'>October</option>
        <option value='11'>November</option>
        <option value='12'>December</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Day -->
        </td><td align="left">   
        <select name="dapurd">
        <option value='01'>01</option>
        <option value='02'>02</option>
        <option value='03'>03</option>
        <option value='04'>04</option>
        <option value='05'>05</option>
        <option value='06'>06</option>
        <option value='07'>07</option>
        <option value='08'>08</option>
        <option value='09'>09</option>
        <option value='10'>10</option>
        <option value='11'>11</option>
        <option value='12'>12</option>
        <option value='13'>13</option>
        <option value='14'>14</option>
        <option value='15'>15</option>
        <option value='16'>16</option>
        <option value='17'>17</option>
        <option value='18'>18</option>
        <option value='19'>19</option>
        <option value='20'>20</option>
        <option value='21'>21</option>
        <option value='22'>22</option>
        <option value='23'>23</option>
        <option value='24'>24</option>
        <option value='25'>25</option>
        <option value='26'>26</option>
        <option value='27'>27</option>
        <option value='28'>28</option>
        <option value='29'>29</option>
        <option value='30'>30</option>
        <option value='31'>31</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Year -->
        </td><td  align="left"  >   
        <input type="text" name="dapury" size="4" placeholder="year">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="label">Place of purchase</div> <!--Place of purchase-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="plpur" size="60px"></div>
    <div class="label">Name of Dealer</div> <!--Name of dealer-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="namedea" size="60px"></div>
    <div class="space"><b>Price:</b></div>
    <div class="label">Amount</div> <!--Price-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="amount"></div>
    <div class="label">Currency</div> <!--Currency-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="currency"></div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="space"><b>Code Number:</b></div> <!--Code Number-->
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="label">Locator</div> <!--Locator-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="locator"></div>
    <div class="label">General Classification</div> <!--General Classification-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="genclass"></div>
    <div class="label">Specific No.</div> <!--Specific No.-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="specno"></div>
    <div class="label">Author No.</div> <!--Author No.-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="authorno"></div>
    <div class="label">Copyright/Date of Publication</div> <!--Copyright/Date of Publication-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="cdm" placeholder="year" size="5px"></div>
    <div class="label">Volume/Book no.</div> <!--Volume/Book no.-->
    <div class="inputs"><input type="text" name="volb"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php code I used to save it to the database: "savetoinvent.php"

```
<?php
session_start();
//Security and connection to database
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","lemuel","12345"); //connect to the server
      mysql_select_db("integratedlibrarysystem"); //connect to the database

       $query="Select * from libinventuser where username='{$_SESSION['user']}' and password='{$_SESSION['pass']}'";
       $result=mysql_query($query);
       $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num!=0)
        {

        //ACCESSION NUMBER
        //Checking of the last accession number being inputted
        $acce="SELECT MAX(accenum) FROM libinvent";
        $accer=mysql_query($acce);
        $viewuser_row=mysql_fetch_array($accer);

            if($viewuser_row['MAX(accenum)']<1||$viewuser_row['MAX(accenum)']==null){
            $accesnum = 1;
            $_SESSION['accessnum']=$accesnum;
            }
            else{
            $_SESSION['accessnum'] = $_SESSION['accessnum'] + 1;
            }

        //CODE NUMBER
        $locator = $_POST['locator']; //Locator
        $genclass = $_POST['genclass']; //General Classification
        $specno = $_POST['specno']; //Specific Number
        $authorno = $_POST['authorno']; //Author Number
        $dpub = $_POST['cdm']; //Copyright/Date of Publication
        $volb = $_POST['volb']; //Volume or Book Number

        //AUTHOR    
        //Getting the value of Author(s)
        $ctr = $_POST['ctr']; //author counter
        if($ctr==null){
        $ctr=1; //counting the number of Authors
        }
        $lasttemp="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$ctr; $i++){
            $lasttemp.=$_POST['l'.$i].', '.$_POST['f'.$i].' '.$_POST['m'.$i].';'; //temp = temp + last, first and middle names
        }

        //TITLE
        $title = $_POST['title'];

        //EDITION
        $edition = $_POST['edition'];

        //PLACE OF PUBLICATION
        $place = $_POST['place'];

        //DATE OF PUBLICATION
        $datepub = $_POST['cpdm'].'-'.$_POST['cpdd'].'-'.$_POST['cpdy'];

        //NUMBER OF PAGES
        $nopa = $_POST['nopa'];

        //NUMBER OF COPIES
        $nocop = $_POST['nocop'];

        //DATE OF PURCHASE
        $datepurch = $_POST['dapurm'].'-'.$_POST['dapurd'].'-'.$_POST['dapury'];

        //PLACE OF PURCHASE
        $plpur = $_POST['plpur'];

        //NAME OF DEALER
        $namedea = $_POST['namedea'];

        //PRICE
        $price = $_POST['currency'].' '.$_POST['amount']; //Currency and Amount

        //SUBJECT MATTER    
        //Getting the value of subject(s)
        $ctra = $_POST['ctra']; //subject counter
        if($ctra==null){
        $ctra=1; //counting the number of Authors
        }
        $lasttempa="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$ctra; $i++){
            $lasttempa.=$_POST['s'.$i].';'; //temp = temp + last, first and middle names
        }

        //Saving the details into the database
        $query1="Insert into libinvent values('{$_SESSION['accessnum']}', '$locator', '$genclass', '$specno', 
        '$authorno', '$dpub', '$volb', '$lasttemp', '$title', '$edition', '$place', '$datepub', '$nopa', 
        '$nocop', '$datepurch', '$plpur', '$namedea' ,'$price' ,'$lastempa')";
        $result1=mysql_query($query1);


        //Searching
        $data=explode(';', $lasttemp);
        for($i=0; $i<=$ctr; $i++){
        echo $data[$i].'; ';
        }
        //Author counter


        if(mysql_affected_rows()==1){
            echo "message sent!";
            echo '<a href="_invent.php">GO Back</a>';
            }
            }


?>
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to:

```
<form method="POST" action="savetoinvent.php">
  <div id="forminput">
    <?php include('addmaterialform.php'); //Add material form?> 
    <div class="space"><input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" /></div>
  </div>
  <div id="formconfirm" style="display: none">
    <div id="formconfirminner"></div>
    <br/><input type="submit" id="saveconfirm" value="Hell Yeah!" /> <a href="#" id="cancelconfirm">Errr... no....</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Add something like the following javascript/jquery:

```
//Keep the actual save button, in case the user disables javascript. This way, they can still
//submit the form. If javascript is enabled, cancle the submission otherwise to show the confirmation
$('#save').on( 'click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the click event trigger submitting the form
  $('#forminput').hide();
  $('#formconfirm').show();
  $('#formconfirminner').html( preparesomethingfancy() );
} );

$('#cancelconfirm').on( 'click', function( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#forminput').show();
  $('#formconfirm').hide();
  $('#formconfirminner').html( '' );
} );

function preparesomethingfancy() {
  //Here you prepare the html to display in the confirmation message
  var output = "";
  output += "Title: " + $('#title').prop( 'value' );
  output += "<br/><br/>Do you really want to strive for world domination?";
  return output;
}
```

This code will show the confirmation dialog without reloading the page. When submitting the form it will reload/load savetoinvent.php.

Documentation about used functions:

- [`jQueryElement.on(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`jQueryElement.hide(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [`jQueryElement.show(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`jQueryElement.html(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)
- [`jQueryElement.prop(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [`jQueryElement.attr(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EuJBq/1/

---

On a side-note: `mysql_*` in php are deprecated functions. You are encouraged to use either the `mysqli_*` functions or the PDO functions for new projects.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But what I wanted is to display the fields that I input on the text boxes and display it into a confirm box before saving it to the database.

Comment: That's what `preparesomethingfancy()` is for. I've added 1 example to the answer.